# HTTP_ORIGIN header not being sent via jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am learning about and fiddling with cross-domain requests via jquery. I made a php script that would print all headers it receives

```
foreach ($_SERVER as $header=>$value){
        echo "$header:$value \n";
    }
```

An then I issued an ajax request via jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://cin.ufpe.br/~rvcam/test',
    success:addData,
    crossDomain:true,
    contentType:'text/plain',
    error:function(xhr, status, error){alert(status+error);}
});
```

(note that I set crossDomain as true to ensure the request would be treated as CORS)

But the return of the php file is

```
UNIQUE_ID:U-oSxqwVAAMAAAqLS80AAAAa 
HTTP_HOST:cin.ufpe.br 
HTTP_CONNECTION:keep-alive 
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL:no-cache 
HTTP_PRAGMA:no-cache 
HTTP_ACCEPT:*/* 
HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36 
CONTENT_TYPE:text/plain 
HTTP_REFERER:http://dresdencodak.com/2007/05/22/for-lack-of-a-better-term/ 
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip,deflate,sdch 
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6 
HTTP_COOKIE:__utma=126956233.172626394.1408376074.1408376074.1408376074.1; __utmc=126956233; __utmz=126956233.1408376074.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=        (none); _ga=GA1.2.172626394.1408376074 
PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin 
SERVER_SIGNATURE: 
SERVER_SOFTWARE:Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) 
SERVER_NAME:cin.ufpe.br 
SERVER_ADDR:172.21.0.3 
SERVER_PORT:80 
REMOTE_ADDR:172.23.16.229 
DOCUMENT_ROOT:/etc/apache2/htdocs 
SERVER_ADMIN:webmaster@localhost 
SCRIPT_FILENAME:/home/rvcam/public_html/test/index.php 
REMOTE_PORT:59739 
GATEWAY_INTERFACE:CGI/1.1 
SERVER_PROTOCOL:HTTP/1.1 
REQUEST_METHOD:GET 
QUERY_STRING: 
REQUEST_URI:/~rvcam/test/ 
SCRIPT_NAME:/~rvcam/test/index.php 
PHP_SELF:/~rvcam/test/index.php 
REQUEST_TIME:1408897734
```

As you see, no "origin" header. Also, I don't know if this is relevant, but the script is running from a chrome extension.

**EDIT** The context is not important, since I've put the same script on my page and the problem persisted.

Comment: @morefromalan I think you can answer this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Origin` header is only sent for cross-origin requests that require [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors). When you declare the host permissions in the manifest file, as in `"permissions": ["http://example.com/*"]`, then any request to example.com within your extension will *not* use CORS.

If you want to identify requests from your Chrome extension, simply add a custom header:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    crossDomain: false,
    headers: {
        'X-My-Header': 'my header'
    }
});
```

or in vanilla JS:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', 'http://example.com');
x.setRequestHeader('X-My-Header', 'my header');
x.send();
```

Do NOT forget to check that the request does NOT have a `Origin` request header. By checking that the Origin header does not exist, you know for sure that the request was made by a page at the same origin, or your extension.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies precisely in the fact that the script is being executed from a Chrome Extension. XHR requests must be allowed from the user.

You must add in your manifest.json the "permissions" propriety, just like this

```
"permissions": [
  "http://www.example.com/",
  "https://www.example.com/"
]
```

Reload the extension and it shoud be work.

[See more about XHR on Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)